# Mass transfer case Owner through Inline editing

Tags: lightning

I want to do Mass transfer case Owner through Inline editing, for that I have created one custom list view, filtered it with one record type. I tried to change case owner it is not editable showing lock option, where other fields like subject is Inline editable.
I checked this with various filter combination to Inline edit the case owner as well as checked appropriate permissions for that as per the article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003911&type=1

[image]

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Are you able to change the owner from the detail page?

Comment: yes I am able to change owner from detail page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue for the Winter 18 release and it is in review state. Please find the below link from Salesforce.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EJkXQAW&title=owner-name-field-is-not-inline-editable-in-lightning-experience-in-winter-18

You can also mark it as "The Issue Affects me".